# Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"

Tags: .net, youtube, oauth-2.0, youtube-data-api

I am uploading video from local to youtube.

In local server it is working fine and authenticating window is getting opened . But while uploading video , this below code I am running and getting this error.

```
2017-04-22 02:57:34.275 -05:00 [Information] C:\Backups\inetpub\YouTube\client_secrets.json
2017-04-22 02:57:34.479 -05:00 [Information] ==========Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=357849494845-pg20dbmdnhoi5gk8go2bakbs9q8635q8.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost:53639%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https:%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.upload" for authorization. See inner exception for details.=============
2017-04-22 02:57:34.481 -05:00 [Information] ==========   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.<ReceiveCodeAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.<AuthorizeAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.<AuthorizeAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.<AuthorizeAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at YoutubeApiDemo.classes.UploadVideo.<Run>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Users\GLB-008PC\Desktop\New folder\YoutubeApiDemo\src\YoutubeApiDemo\classes\UploadVideo.cs:line 45=============
2017-04-22 02:57:34.487 -05:00 [Debug] Executed action method "YoutubeApiDemo.Controllers.HomeController.UploadVideo (YoutubeApiDemo)", returned result "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ContentResult".
2017-04-22 02:57:34.488 -05:00 [Information] Executing ContentResult with HTTP Response ContentType of "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
2017-04-22 02:57:34.489 -05:00 [Information] Executed action "YoutubeApiDemo.Controllers.HomeController.UploadVideo (YoutubeApiDemo)" in 224.0549ms
2017-04-22 02:57:34.489 -05:00 [Information] Request finished in 226.4115ms 200 text/plain; charset=utf-8
2017-04-22 02:57:34.489 -05:00 [Debug] Connection id ""0HL49AKRM6GUK"" completed keep alive response.
```

My code to perform this task is :

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(client_secret_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                       credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                       GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                      new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                      username,
                      CancellationToken.None,
                      new FileDataStore("YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;

                }
```